# Issue in converting all "import * from" to "const * = req() in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, requirejs, require

There is import function:
`import socketIO, { Server as SocketIOServer } from "socket.io";`

i want to convert this to
`const socketIO, { Server as SocketIOServer } = require("socket.io")`

But it is not working, what would by type format in require?

`

error:
TS1005',' expected

Comment: Why would you even do that?

Comment: There is a whole project of mine where i have to integrate the webrtc, i have found an example code, but in that code the developer used "import" function and in my code i have "const" function for requiring packages.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković it still gives the error "TS1005 ',' expected.

Comment: `const { Server: SocketIOServer, default: socketIO  } = require("socket.io")` Sorry, wrong paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved with the following code:

```
const { Server: SocketIOServer, default: socketIO  } = require("socket.io")
```